# Unable to install Docker-Desktop on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, dependencies, docker

I am trying to install `docker-desktop` on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. However, when I try to run the following command, it shows errors.

```
sudo apt install ./docker-desktop-*-amd64.deb
```

The output of this command is:

```
Reading package lists...
Done Building dependency tree...
Done Reading state information...
Done
Note, selecting 'docker-desktop' instead of './docker-desktop-4.12.0-amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an
impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
docker-desktop : Depends: pass but it is not installable 
                 Depends: uidmap but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Reading package lists...
Done
```

I have already installed `docker`:

```
$ docker -v 
Docker version 23.0.0, build e92dd87
```

Comment: This answer do not solve the problem. In my case, two dependencies are unmet i.e. "pass" and "uidmap". I do not know how to resolve these dependencies.

Comment: It seems you need to add the `universe` repo. I also added this to the other Q&A .. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't have the `universe` repository enabled. Enable with this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

This should enable the installation of the remaining packages (`pass` and `uidmap`).

Comment: thank you. The problem is resolved by enabling repository.